# Intermediate values during folding?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a collection of objects

```
case class Record(value: Whatever)
val list: List[Record]
```

and want to select the best ranked

```
list.foldLeft(list.head) { (best, current) =>
    if (rank(current.value) > rank(best.value)) {
        current
    } else {
        best
    }
}
```

Let's suppose that `rank` is expensive and better not be called twice on the same object. What are my options?

I can fold to tuple `(rank, record)` but this probably means creating auxiliary objects during iteration. Should I worry about the overhead? Or rather

1. How can this be implemented efficiently in Scala?
2. What's the proper 'functional' view of the problem?

Comment: It sounds like you want `maxBy(rank)`

Comment: I'm ashamed to have forgotten about this. Indeed `maxBy` is an efficient out-of-the-box solution with `var` under the hood.

Answer (score 4):

If you're in a situation where repeating expensive calculations on the same objects appears unavoidable, you might try memoization.

```
// memoize this function (arity 1)
def memo[A,R](f :A => R): A => R =
  new collection.mutable.WeakHashMap[A,R] {
    override def apply(a: A) = getOrElseUpdate(a,f(a))
  }

// rankM is a memoized Record => Rank function
val rankM = memo{ r:Record => rank(r.value) }
```

A `WeakHashMap` is used sometimes when you want the `Map` to "forget" seldom accessed keys in a memory-challenged environment.

Comment: Thank you for the idea but this is far off the original question. There is no need to keep more than value during calculations. And this value is needed only during traversing.

Answer (score 3):

The initial value in foldLeft can be of a different type than collection, so you could initialize it with tuple, that would contain current element and calculated value:

```
val (result, _) = list.foldLeft((list.head, rank(list.head))) { case ((best, bestRank), current) =>
    val currentRank = rank(current.value)
    if (rank(current.value) > bestRank) {
      (current, currentRank)
    } else {
      (best, bestRank)
    }
}
```

But as was mentioned in comments maybe in your case, it would be better to just use: `list.maxBy(r => rank(r.value))` ?