# How to avoid duplicate calculation in partial functions?

Tags: scala

Here is a simplified code snippet:

```
val pf = new PartialFunction[Int, Int]
{
    private def calc(x: Int): Int = x - 3

    override def isDefinedAt(x: Int): Boolean =
        {
            val result = calc(x)
            println(s"calc is called by isDefinedAt, result = $result")
            result > 0
        }

    override def apply(x: Int): Int =
        {
            val result = calc(x)
            println(s"calc is called by apply, result = $result")
            result
        }
}

(0 to 6).collect(pf)
```

The output is:

```
calc is called by isDefinedAt, result = -3
calc is called by isDefinedAt, result = -2
calc is called by isDefinedAt, result = -1
calc is called by isDefinedAt, result = 0
calc is called by isDefinedAt, result = 1
calc is called by apply, result = 1
calc is called by isDefinedAt, result = 2
calc is called by apply, result = 2
calc is called by isDefinedAt, result = 3
calc is called by apply, result = 3
```

Here, the *calc* method is called twice for result 1, 2, 3. Suppose that the the *calc* method is costly, then how to avoid duplicate calls to it for each call to the partial function *pf*?

Answer (score 2):

There is not much you can do to minimise the amount of calls to internal `calc` method. `isDefinedAt` and `apply` are independent methods and you cannot make any assumptions of the way these methods are used by the caller.

One approach is to cache the input argument `x` and the result of `calc` method. This is not easy to do, may introduce nasty bugs, overcomplicate your code and of course increase memory footprint.

I'd focus on reducing time/memory complexity of the `calc` method before considering applying any cache solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a better way is avoid using `partition function` and just use `flatMap` with `Option` for filtering not defined inputs in `calc`:

```
private def calc(x: Int): Int = x - 3

(0 to 6).flatMap(x => Option(calc(x)).filter(_ > 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try some form of [memoization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61675508/5205022) like so

```
val pf = new PartialFunction[Int, Int] {
  private val expensiveCalc = (x: Int) => x - 3

  private val calc = new collection.mutable.WeakHashMap[Int, Int] {
    override def apply(a: Int) = getOrElseUpdate(a, expensiveCalc(a))
  }

  override def isDefinedAt(x: Int): Boolean = calc(x) > 0
  override def apply(x: Int): Int = calc(x)
}

(0 to 6).collect(pf)
```